# "fast ward" clustering in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hierarchical-clustering

In JMP software there is an option to use the "fast Ward" method when the number of rows is greater than 2000.  From the [documentation](https://www.jmp.com/support/help/14/method-for-distance-calculation.shtml) [fast ward]:

"Applies an algorithm that computes Ward's method more quickly for large numbers of rows. The computation time is shorter because this algorithm does not require the calculation of a distance matrix. It is used automatically whenever there are more than 2,000 rows."

[Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/clusterdata.html) does the same thing....
"Find a maximum of four clusters in a hierarchical cluster tree created using the ward linkage method. Specify 'SaveMemory' as 'on' to construct clusters without computing the distance matrix. Otherwise, you can receive an out-of-memory error if your machine does not have enough memory to hold the distance matrix."

I'm looking for something similar in Python but they all seem to require the distance matrix calculated ahead of time (which requires absurd amounts of memory for my problem of 275k rows and 10 columns).  In JMP/Matlab though it works just fine on a machine with half the memory of the machine I want to run the python script on.  Anybody know of something?

Comment: Use the "Add an Answer" button, rather than editing an answer into the question, to write your own answer. (That way, after a delay, you'll be able to accept it and mark the question as closed; that way the answer is also subject to upvotes/downvotes/comments separate from the question itself). See also [Is it better to answer or edit your question to post a solution?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307553/is-it-better-to-answer-or-edit-your-question-to-post-solution) on [meta].

Comment: BTW, while I copied the now-removed self-answer into a community-wiki post, if you want to add your own non-community-wiki answer (so you get any points associated with upvotes), let me know and I'll be glad to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [a now-rolled-back edit to the question by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60162763/3):

> I found that using the "linkage_vector" option seems to be what i was looking for.  I was thrown off because "vector" to me meant 1D, but I guess it can be N-D.

Answer (score 0):

Have you worked with [fastcluster](https://pypi.org/project/fastcluster/)? It has the option for "hierarchical clusters from distance matrices ***or*** from vector data"